# How to separate the footer of a layout with a line in android

Tags: android, android-layout, footer, separator

I am building a page with a Linearlayout and numerous elements within it. At the bottom of the screen, I want to add a line, separating the "footer". How can this be achieved? I was thinking for something as a TextView, and the line to be the text added, but am sure there is a better way to be done. Thanks!

Comment: post your xml file , so people can help you

Comment: Well, I am wondering what to post exactly, no problem otherwise. It's not within an xml, I'm having just the layout. Or probably I need to add an xml and specify the devider there?

Comment: use below answer you got some idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add a view with specify background into the xml layout like below:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this xml for your purpose ...... It just example ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Footer" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:- 2nd Linear layout is For main content .... 3rd Linear layout for footer .....**

output of above xml ..

[image: h]

Comment: Thanks you, it worked with adding the View, I've forgotten of its existence :)))

Answer (score 1):

To Seperate `Footer` from the Container you can add `line` as a Seperator. But I can give better approach you have to add `Shadow` to the `LinearLayout` it will make sense that your Main Container and Footer will be seperate.

My Approach.

**footer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_upper_shadow"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/below_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="0.0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50.0"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin15"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin5"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="$1,605"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize20"
            android:textColor="@color/black1" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin15"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="View price detail"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize13"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continue_button"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/normal_margin8"
        android:layout_weight="50.0"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/continue_string"
        android:textColor="@color/white1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize13" />
</LinearLayout>
```

for separator.

**separator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/linear_layout_shadow"/>
      />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item
      android:left="0dp"
      android:right="0dp"
      android:top="1dp"
      android:bottom="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
      <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OutPut :**

[image]